# Why the results of the command 'date -u' command 'date' faster than the result of 25 seconds in linux(centos 5.1)?

Tags: linux, date, time, utc, localtime

In the CentOS release 5.10, the results of the command 'date -u' command 'date' faster than the result of 25 seconds.

Here is the result:

```
[a@MG11ZA1 b]$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-  ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
Release:        5.10
Codename:       Final
[a@MG11ZA1 b]$ uname -a
Linux MG11ZA1 2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Tue Oct 1 08:35:08 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[a@MG11ZA1 b]$ date && date -u && /usr/sbin/hwclock --show
Fri Jun 26 17:47:42 CST 2015
Fri Jun 26 09:48:07 UTC 2015
Fri 26 Jun 2015 05:47:18 PM CST  -0.235359 seconds
```

And the result of the following code is not right

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm today;
    localtime_r(&now, &today);
    printf(
        "seconds:%d\n"
        "minutes:%d\n"
        "hours:%d\n"
        "day of the month:%d\n"
        "month:%d\n"
        "year:%d\n"
        "day of the week:%d\n"
        "day in the year:%d\n"
        "daylight saving time:%d\n"
            ,today.tm_sec
            ,today.tm_min
            ,today.tm_hour
            ,today.tm_mday
            ,today.tm_mon
            ,today.tm_year
            ,today.tm_wday
            ,today.tm_yday
            ,today.tm_isdst);
    time_t weekstart = now - today.tm_wday * 24*60*60;
    printf("weekstart:%u\n", (unsigned int)weekstart);
    struct tm start;
    localtime_r(&weekstart,&start);
    start.tm_hour = 0;
    start.tm_min  = 0;
    start.tm_sec  = 0;
    unsigned int version = mktime(&start);
    printf("version:%u\n", version);
    return 0;
}
```

The result of above code is:

```
seconds:53
minutes:54
hours:17
day of the month:26
month:5
year:115
day of the week:5
day in the year:176
daylight saving time:0
weekstart:1434880518
version:1434816025
```

The version should be 1434816000 not 1434816025, (now is 2015-06-26).

Thanks for any person to answer

Comment: Due to [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)? Quote: "Since this system of correction was implemented in 1972, 25 such leap seconds have been inserted." Try again next week, after June 30 when another leap second is added, and see if the difference is 26 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, your timezone is `right/PRC`, which is a timezone that is explicitly adjusted for leap seconds. You can see the difference here:

This is `right/PRC`, which does not apply the (current) 25 seconds to the time being reported:

```
env TZ=right/PRC date
Fri Jun 26 19:13:18 CST 2015
```

This is `PRC`, which has applied the (current) 25 seconds to the time being reported:

```
env TZ=PRC date
Fri Jun 26 19:13:43 CST 2015
```

This is `UTC`, which is the same timezone as is reported by `date -u`:

```
env TZ=UTC date
Fri Jun 26 11:13:43 UTC 2015
```

Finally there is `right/UTC`, which is the time without the (current) 25 second adjustment:

```
env TZ=right/UTC date
Fri Jun 26 11:13:18 UTC 2015
```

You should not really be using the `right/` timezones for general use - they do not match the reported time for most producers/consumers of time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but I think the 25 seconds you see is the difference between "normal" and "UTC" time because of the [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). Next month it should be 26 seconds btw.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> Since this system of correction was implemented in 1972, 25 such leap
>   seconds have been inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But why the version of the code is 1434816025?It just should be 1434816000, and it really is 1434816000 in other linux machine.